# Binding DataSet to a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dataset, repeater

I have a `<asp:Repeater>` control and I am binding a `DataSet` to it with a number of different `DataTables`.

I'm confused as to how to access and bind one table at time to my repeater.

I would like to do something like this

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "heading_id") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

...but first for the table one then a new `<tr>` and then data from the table two and so on.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but on a side node, you can replace `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "heading_id") %>` with `<%# Eval("heading_id") %>` - it's a nice little shortcut

Comment: Thank, yes that is what I normally use :)  So the thing that is bound to my Repeater is a DataSet which has multiple tables in it.  So I want to display heading_id from the table[0], then from table[1]... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want nested repeaters, with the outside one representing the DataSet's DataTables, and the inside one representing the rows within a DataTable.

Personally, I've found nested repeaters to be horrible to work with because of the custom data binding, and unless you're doing a lot of event binding, I'd probably go with a more inline approach, something like the following:

```
<% foreach (var dt in MyDataSet.Tables) { %>
    <table>
        <% foreach (var row in dt.Rows) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><label><%= row["heading_id"] %></label></td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
<% } %>
```

In your code-behind, you'd just need to assign your DataSet object to a protected field or property.

Comment: Thanks Joe.   I was actually looking at a nested repeater article online somewhere and I think your approach is much cleaner...  Thank you